# Netty rotating reconnect handler

Tags: sockets, netty, reconnect

I am trying to write a handler in netty which holds a list of n `SocketAddress`. What I would like to happen is start with the first address and try to connect.  If this fails, try the next address and so on.

If the connection drops for any reason then I would like the connection to be retried indefinitely, rotating through the address list.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to go about writing this.  I have found the netty example about doing a single address reconnect handler but not sure about the multiple case.

Answer (score 1):

I thin you could do this easily with a ChannelFutureListener for the connection part. For the connection drop you could write your custom SimpleUpstreamChannelHandler and override the connectionClosed(..) method to handle the "reconnect".